# ByteArrayOutputStream to String Array

Tags: java, string, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm writing an application which has a method that will download a text file from my server. This text file will contain ~1,000 proxy IP's. The download will happen every 10 minutes. I need to find the most efficient way of doing this.

Currently I have a method in a class called Connection which will return the bytes of whatever I want to retrieve. So if I make a connection to the server for the text file using such method, I will get it returned in bytes. My other method will create a very long string from these bytes. After, I split the long string into an array using System.LineSeparator. Here is the code:

```
 public static void fetchProxies(String url) {
    Connection c = new Connection();
    List<Proxy> tempProxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = 
            c.requestBytes(url);  
    String line = new String(baos.toByteArray()); 

    String[] split = line.split(System.lineSeparator());
    //more code to come but the above works fine.

}
```

This currently works but I know that it isn't the most efficient way. I

**My Problem** 
**Instead of turning the bytes into a very long string, what is the most efficient way of turning the bytes into my IP's so I can add each individual IP into an arraylist and then return the arraylist full of IP's?**

Comment: why not you use serialization and deserialization for this purpose .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient and logical way would be to create a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader` wrapping the `InputStream` of the URL connection. You would the use `readLine()` on the `BufferedReader` until it returns null, and append each line read to the list of IP addresses:

```
List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), theAppropriateEncoding))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ipList.add(line);
    }
}
```

Note that this probably won't change much in the performance of the method, though, because most of the time is being spend in waiting fof bytes coming from the remote host, which is considerably slower than building and splitting a String in memory.

Comment: Thanks! So do you suggest I just stick with what I have? I wanted to do it the way you suggested but I decided against it because it would violate the "don't duplicate code" rule. I am doing it the way I provided in my original post because there will be more than one method using that code, so i'm trying to make this as generic as possible. Quite new to Java and I don't know if this is good practice, but from what I read I think it is!

I will accept your answer once you inform me what to do, thanks.

Comment: No, I don't suggest that. The above code is more correct with what you have: it uses the appropriate encoding, and deals with any kind of line terminator sequence correctly: the line separator of the system is not necessarily the line separator used in the file. I don't really see how the aboce code violates any duplication rule. What does it duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

split method from String isn't the fastest way to separate all the IP's. There ara other libraries to achive this in an more optimized way. 
Read this: http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/

There is a very nice time comparision about 7 different ways to split a String.

For example a the Splitter class from Guava library returns an Iterable, and with Guava you could also convert the results as List:

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
...
public static void fetchProxies(String url) {
Connection c = new Connection();
List<Proxy> tempProxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = 
        c.requestBytes(url);  
String line = new String(baos.toByteArray()); 

Iterator<Element> myIterator = 
    Splitter.on(System.getProperty("line.separator")).split(line);
List<Element> myList = Lists.newArrayList(myIterator);

// do somethjing with the List...
```

Comment: @exoddus I think that should be Iterable instead of Iterator.